# cdo:(Abort): Unprocessed Input, could not process all Operators/Files

Tags: cdo-climate

I am trying to use billinear interpolation to extract a specific location from my file but I get the error: cdo:(Abort): Unprocessed Input, could not process all Operators/Files

```
cdo remapbil,lon = 12/lat=55 1979-1982_d.nc 1979-1984_cph.nc
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove some of the spaces. This should work.

```
cdo remapbil,lon=1/lat=55 1979-1982_d.nc 1979-1984_cph.nc
```

CDO has to be able to parse your command. Roughly speaking your command is "cdo remapinstruction infile outfile". So spaces are critical for CDO understanding the command. Because you have a space where it shouldn't be, CDO is not able to parse the command properly.